# Redirecting to a different page when clicking in the back button "not working"

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that  once it's submitted it' takes the user to a "Thanks page"  the idea   is that if the user clicks in the back button, instead of going back to the form it takes the user to  a different page.  I'm using `src="backfix.min.js"` which is properly in a .js file. Is alerting the message  but for some reason it's not taking the user to the page i want to.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Thank You!</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="backfix.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function()
{    
alert("Will take you back to the main page");
document.location.href = 'http://goggle.com'; 
};
</script>  
</head>

<body  style="background-color: white" >
<div align="center" >           
<img  alt="thanyou" src="Images/thank_you[2].png" width="800" height="600"> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can try window.location.href

Comment: `window.location.href ` instead of `document.location.href `

Comment: using window.location.href the same happends: alert the message but when i click Ok takes me back to the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser Back button run `window.history.back()`.

Thus, Use `window.history.back` & Override it :

```
bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function()
{   
     alert("Will take you back to the main page");
      window.history.back=function(){document.location='http://google.com';};

  }
```

It works for me known that i mean by `back.fix`  [this Library](https://code.google.com/p/group972301/source/browse/ep%20web%20for%20checkout/WebContent/js/backfix.min.js?r=61)

**UPDATE :**

This is [my example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55765722/delivred/abdennour/lib/js/backfix.html#b) :

If does not work yet . Wrap All code in `setTimeout` function :

```
setTimeout(function(){

  bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function()
    {   
      alert("Will take you back to the main page");
      window.history.back=function(){document.location='http://google.com'}
    }
 },200)
```

Comment: what is the timeout at the end (200) for, what is the difference between the first one and this one?

Comment: it is 200 millisecondes. IT is just a prevention to wait all JS object to be ready (i.e: window.history) .